# Documents for Spouse with B1/B2 visa accompanying on a business trip of husband to USA from India

Tags: customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, b1-b2-visas, us-visa

I am travelling from India to USA on a business trip. My wife has a B1/B2 visa and will be accompanying me as a visitor. She is already employed in India, she will be on leave for the duration of the visit. Please help me with the documents that she should carry. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Documents for what? She already has a visa. The majority of people with visas do not carry documents along on the trip. If you’re feeling anxious a bank statement and letter of authorized leave from her company is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The majority of people with valid visas do not carry documents along on the trip.

A bank statement and letter of authorized leave from her company should be sufficient in case she’s asked. Actually saying she’s traveling with you should be enough if you have documents covering your trip. It’s accepted that spouses sometimes travel together on business trips.

You should walk up to the immigration officer together, as a family. Unless you have other immigration issues you have not mentioned, there should not be a problem.

Comment: My edit: tiny typo